# I can't figure out how to reinstall windows

Tags: boot, windows, uninstall

I wanted to try Ubuntu out, but now that I've tried it I don't really think it is for me and I want to go back to Windows 10.  I can't figure out how though.  I don't know anything about Ubuntu, and I tried using a Windows 10 recovery disk, but Ubuntu seems to just ignore it.  I can't figure out how to get Ubuntu off my computer.

It is really starting to stress me out, I've been googling for hours trying to figure this out, but every answer I find assumes I can do things that I can't even figure out how to do.

The most I've been able to do is get to some boot menu that lets me either boot Ubuntu normally, or do advanced options that just gives me 4 Ubuntu options.  I have access to command thing and something else by typing 'e' or 'c', but I have no idea what to do in either of those to help.

If I had known how difficult it was going to be to go back I'd have never installed Ubuntu in the first place.

I feel like I need someone to walk me through the entire process because I have no idea what I am doing, and google searches never give me answers that help me.

Comment: You should ask for help installing Windows on [superuser.se] since it is not about Ubuntu. Would also recommend following http://decentsecurity.com/#/securing-your-computer/

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? How to restore the Ubuntu/XP/Vista/7/8/10 BIOS bootloader 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader AND if UEFI: Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu

Answer (score 2):

You need to hold a button upon booting your computer that will let you boot from external media (it should be called something along the lines "boot menu"). The exact key combination varies from computer to computer by I've seen `F12` and `delete`.

Comment: Thank you!  Your comment helped me find out how to boot from the disk.  I am installing windows now!!